# How to stop a code pipeline using lambda when there are vulnerabilities detected in Amazon Web Services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ecr

I have a code pipeline that continuously scans for Vulnerabilities in the Docker Container.
So if the scanned images contain vulnerabilities pipeline should be stopped further deploying it.
I'm using Cloudwatch ECR Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

1)Using cloudwatch events you can create a rule
        Service Name: Elastic Container Registry (ECR)
        Event Type: ECR Image Scan
2)for this rule add SNS topic as target
        Topic: SNS
3)before adding target configure sns topic
        1)create topic with your desired name
        2)create subscription with desired protocol
          here I created email as my protocol 
4)Once the image scanning is done cloud watch trigger a mail containing vulnerabilities of the Docker Image with all the details.
5)If vulnerabilities found stop the pipeline using manual approval task or else configure the Aws Lambda